# How to find multiline attributes using Sublime Text

Tags: html, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I been using `style='(.*?)` (in the find box) to replace the entire style attribute:

Example:

```
<a style='width: 68px';text-align:center'> < /a>
```

How can i do to find multiline style?

Example:

```
<a style='width: 68px';text-align:center;
 padding:0cm 3.5pt 0cm 3.5pt;height:90.0pt'> < /a>
```

Note: The original code is from office word (table) export (that's why multiline attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
style='((.|\n)*?)'
```

The only difference is that `.` was replaced by `(.|\n)` which matches `.` or new line characters `\n`. If you use `\r\n` as end of line sequence, you need to use that sequence instead of `\n`.

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/98oO03/1).